# how to compare server time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, date-comparison

work on Sql server 2000. i want to get the current server date and time then want to compare it with my table column EntryDate .How to?

```
Declare @id datetime

Select @id = DATEPART(hour,GETDATE())

SELECT [Name],[BirthDate],[Email]
FROM Customers3 where BirthDate<=@id-1 AND BirthDate>=@id
```

**want to get on the range value like @id=10.I want to get those values whose are between 9 to 10**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the query along the DatePart() like this:

```
Declare @id datetime

Select @id = DATEPART(hour,GETDATE())

SELECT [Name],[BirthDate],[Email]
FROM Customers3 
where DatePart(HOUR,BirthDate) between @id-1 AND @id
```

Comment: While that would work, if there were an index on the birthdate column - your query wouldn't use it due to performing a function on the column before the comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
WHERE t.birthdate BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Reference: [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258267%28SQL.80%29.aspx)